# Blender 3.0 - A.N.T. Landscape add-on: Erosion is not generating vertex groups

Tags: add-on

Expectedly, when I create a landscape with A.N.T. add-on then click the Landscape Eroder button, there should be vertex groups generated automatically and listed on the right side.

But when I click the Landscape Eroder there is an error occured and no vertex group generated. What did I do wrong?[image]

what it should be looked like (2.93 version):
[image]

my version(3.0 version):
[image]

Comment: With just a quick look-see I would agree that this appears to be dysfunctional in v3.x.  I suggest you use the Help menu to Report A Bug, and for now you'll have to continue to use the older blender version with this Add-On.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is currently broken, with a fix incoming. For a quick workaround, you can apply the fix provided [here](https://developer.blender.org/T74604).